# expand a matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, rows

I want to put constraints of my Linear Program in the rows of a matrix.
I get the constraints out of the elements of a list, but several elements of the list consist of a zero vector. The corresponding constraints don't matter in my case and don't have to be in the constraint matrix.

Is there a way to define your matrix in advance such that you can keep adding rows to the matrix without worrying about the size of your matrix. You just want to keep adding rows to matrix and at the end you will see how many rows your matrix has.

Here is the code so far:

```
B<-matrix(HERE TO DO THE TRICK SUCH THAT THE FOR LOOP BELOW GIVES NO ERROR)

for (i in 1:(length(cars))){
  if (sum(cars[[i]])) > 0{
      B[i,]<-cars[[i]]
  }
}
```

`cars` is a list with in each element a vector.
I don't want to unlist because my list is too big and due to that I want to get rid of the elements that have a vector that consists of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a matrix of `NA`'s

```
B <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(cars[[1]]), nrow = (length(cars)))
```

then run your loop to fill the matrix

```
for (i in 1:(length(cars))){
  if (sum(cars[[i]])) > 0{
      B[i,]<-cars[[i]]
  }
}
```

and exclude all rows with `NA` after that

```
B <- B[-which(is.na(B[ ,1])), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `rbind()`. It combines the rows of multiple data frames (or matrices). See `cbind()` to combine columns.

```
cars <- 1:5
B <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(cars)){
  B <- rbind(B, mtcars[i, ])
}
B
##                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

To combine multiple multidimensional arrays, see the `abind` package.

Comment: Actually, P.Burns in [https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf](R Inferno) warns against using rbind inside loops due to inefficient memory usage...